# How to register listener to Actions stored in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, listener, action

For a game I'm developing I'm keeping track of a GameState to determine which systems should be active. To enable systems to register themselves to State changes, I've written the following code:

```
    public static Action<State> OnDefaultStateChange;
    public static Action<State> OnConstructionStateChange;

    private static Dictionary<GameState, Action<State>> _stateChangeActions =
        new Dictionary<GameState, Action<State>>()
        {
            {GameState.Default, OnDefaultStateChange},
            {GameState.Construction, OnConstructionStateChange}
        };
```

When a state is changed, it invokes the relevant action by looking up the GameState key in the _stateChangeActions dictionary.
Here's the strange behaviour that I can't understand. 
If I subscribe to the action by using `_stateChangeActions[key] += ListenerMethod;`, it invokes correctly. But if I subscribe on the public static field, e.g `OnDefaultStateChange += ListenerMethod;`, and I invoke the action through the dictionary, it's as if there are no listeners.

I haven't been able to find out why this happens. Note: I'm using Unity Engine, and this issue isn't blocking me, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer to your question

`OnDefaultStateChange` and `_stateChangeActions` have no relation to each other, other than the fact you use `OnDefaultStateChange` to initialize `_stateChangeActions`.
Your line with `{GameState.Default, OnDefaultStateChange},` adds the *object* inside `OnDefaultStateChange` to the dictionary and **not** the *reference*, which means that `_stateChangeActions[GameState.Default]` is not the same as `OnDefaultStateChange`.

An example to show what is actually going on in your setup:

```
var state = new { LivesLeft = 2, ShirtColor = "brown" };

// Corresponds to 'OnDefaultStateChange'
Action<State> someAction = (s) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Lives: " + s.LivesLeft);
};

// Corresponds to '_stateChangeActions'
Action<State> copyOfSomeAction = someAction;

// Subscribe to "OnDefaultStateChange"
someAction += (s) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Shirt color: " + s.ShirtColor);
};

// 'someAction' is longer equal to 'copyOfSomeAction' since 'someAction'
// has been replaced with a new Action which produces the result from two other
// Actions.

someAction(state);
// Output:
// Lives: 2
// Shirt color: brown

copyOfSomeAction(state);
// Output:
// Lives: 2
```

As you can see `OnDefaultStateChange` and `_stateChangeActions` works as two independent objects, so "subscribing" to `OnDefaultStateChange` doesn't make that new subscriber available to `_stateChangeActions`.

#### How to solve your issue

I would suggest you make use of the [event features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) in C#. I'm guessing a little on how you actually check the type of event to fire, but your event handling class could look something like this:

```
// MyEventHandlerClass.cs
public delegate void StateChangedEventHandler(object sender, State state);
public static event StateChangedEventHandler DefaultStateChanged;
public static event StateChangedEventHandler ConstructionStateChanged;

private static FireNewStateChangeEvent(State state) {
    switch (state.StateChangeType)
    {
        case GameState.Default:
            DefaultStateChanged.Invoke(this, state);
        case GameState.Construction:
            ConstructionStateChanged.Invoke(this, state);
    }
}
```

To subscribe to events you simply do pretty much like you already do:

```
MyEventHandlerClass.DefaultStateChanged += ListenerMethod;
```

With this setup you can subscribe or unsubscribe (`-=`) to events from wherever.